# Widget to unmount SD card quickly?

Tags: android, memory-card

I unmount my SD card a lot, and I find it annoying to have to navigate through the settings app each time to safely unmount the SD card. I would like a widget that can do this, or some other simple thing like a drawer in the notification menu.

I'm running Android 4.4.4 and I am rooted and using Xposed Framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Widgetsoid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2&hl=en) which can create a Unmount SD Card widget in your homescreen

Or

You can use [QuickShortCut Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) or [Activity Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher&hl=en) to create a short cut in your homescreen for the Unmount SD Card Activity.

Unmount SD Card activity is com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$StorageSettingsActivity

Comment: I installed all these apps and looked at their interfaces, but I don't understand how to make any of them create a shortcut or widget. Would you care to elaborate?